# Position dodge does not work with geom_point and geom_errorbar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this overplotting issue going on. Even after reading a lot of posts on dodge, jitter and jitter dodge in all kinds of implementations I can't figure it out.

Here you can get my data: http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=uPXN7nPt

```
library(dplyr)
library(gdata)
library(ggplot2)
library(directlabels)


all<-read.xls('all_auto_bio_adjusted_c.xls')
all$size.new<-sqrt(all$size.new)
all$station<-as.factor(all$station)
all$group.new<-factor(all$group, levels=c('C. hyperboreus','C. glacialis','Special Calanus','M. longa','Pseudocalanus sp.','Copepoda'))

pd <- position_dodge(w = 50) 

allp <- ggplot(data = all, aes(y = averagebiol, x = automatic, colour = group.new, group=group.new)) + 
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1) +
  geom_point(aes(size = size.new), show_guide=TRUE, position=pd) +
  scale_size_identity()+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = averagebiol - stdevbiol, ymax = averagebiol +   stdevbiol),colour = "grey", width = 0.1, position=pd) +
  facet_grid(group.new~station, scales="free") +
  xlab("Automatic identification") + ylab("Manual identification") +
  ggtitle("Comparison of automatic vs manual identification") + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.8, face="bold", size=20,vjust=1), axis.text.x = element_text(colour="grey20",size=15,angle=0,hjust=.5,vjust=.5,face="bold"), axis.text.y = element_text(colour="grey20",size=15,angle=0,hjust=1,vjust=0,face="bold"),  axis.title.x = element_text(colour="grey20",size=20,angle=0,hjust=.5,vjust=0,face="bold"), axis.title.y = element_text(colour="grey20",size=20,angle=90,hjust=.5,vjust=1,face="bold"), legend.position="none", strip.text.x = element_text(size = 12, face="bold", colour = "black", angle = 0), strip.text.y = element_text(size = 12, face="bold", colour = "black"))

allp
```

Which produces this nice plot [image]

But as you can see a lot of the points and error bars are cramped together. Shouldn't my implementation of position dodge work?

If I understood right position dodge takes the scale of the axes, so with a doge of 50 I should see some results. I also tried putting the dodge argument directly into the geom, but that had no effect either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you leave out `position = pd` in both `geom_errorbar()` and `geom_point()` you get the same plot. The reason the data look 'cramped' is because of the spread of the x-values. As far as I know, dodging will only happen if two points 'overlap', which I interpret as having the same x-value, e.g. data on a categorical x-axis like in the case of a bar plot. Your x-axis is continuous so the points will not be dodged.

To deal with the overplotting you could try logarithmic scales:

```
library(ggplot2)

tmp <- tempfile()
download.file("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=uPXN7nPt", tmp)
all <- read.csv(tmp)

all$size.new <- sqrt(all$size.new)
all$station <- as.factor(all$station)
all$group.new <- factor(all$group, levels = c("C. hyperboreus", "C. glacialis", 
                                              "Special Calanus", "M. longa",
                                              "Pseudocalanus sp.", "Copepoda"))

# explicitly remove missing data
all <- all[complete.cases(all), ]

allp <- ggplot(data = all, aes(y = averagebiol, x = automatic, colour = group.new, 
                               group = group.new, ymin = averagebiol - stdevbiol,
                               ymax = averagebiol + stdevbiol)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1) + 
  geom_errorbar(colour = "grey", width = 0.1) +
  geom_point(aes(size = size.new)) +
  scale_size_area() + # Just so I could see all the points on my monitor :)
  xlab("Automatic identification") + 
  ylab("Manual identification") +
  ggtitle("Comparison of automatic vs manual identification")

allp + scale_x_log10() +
  scale_y_log10() +
  facet_grid(group.new ~ station, scales = "fixed")
```

Comment: Although maybe I misunderstood what you're trying to do with `position_dodge()`?

Comment: Thanks! I am looking for a way to stop the overplotting of datapoints and error bars.

Comment: I would not use `position_dodge()` for this. I'm not sure it even makes sense with a continuous axis. You could try to address the spread of your data instead e.g. with a transformation or log scales. Good luck!